# Can I run a propane generator under a house on stilts?

Tags: propane

We live in a house on stilts. The height of stilts is about 14'-15'. It is all open air on every side. Is it safe to run the propane generator under the house?

Comment: Is it on stilts due to flooding potential? Aren't you worried about the generator being flooded?

Comment: Leaving as a comment since I don’t know your jurisdiction. With the open area you describe it would be safe but I would add Co (carbon monoxide) detectors in the living spaces above. Carbon monoxide is lighter than air so it will rise (plus being hot) some jurisdictions limit the locations that can be used but at this height and being open I would not be concerned.

Comment: @EdBeal  Would change the word 'would' to 'should'.  Imagine most times it should be okay, but you know every so often any wind will die down to nothing.  Think most places would not say it is allowed underneath living space, even attached garages are a no-no.  My local, every home must CO detectors, still read stories of families being found dead.

Comment: @ I lost a friend to CO poisoning so I take it seriously. If the home doesn’t have any gas appliances they may not have a requirement for a detector. Having wired a few generators the main thing was being 5’ away from windows , the are was described as completely open and they were using propane not gasoline/ Diesel liquid fuels are the reason for the 5’ in my area but natural gas can be within the envelope as long as the exhaust pipe extends 18” wind or not. But I did preface with the jurisdiction.

Comment: I would suggest consulting with your local building authority to find out if it's even allowed. For all the cautionary reasons in these comments, they may have outlawed it. _IF_ it's allowed, then you need to take into consideration the cautions and decide if _you_ are willing to take the risks or if you're OK with them.